# When should it work when you redfine a method?

Tags: ruby

In [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/), `about_open_classes.rb` section, the final test is this:

```
class ::Integer
  def even?
    (self % 2) == 0
  end
end

def test_even_existing_built_in_classes_can_be_reopened
  assert_equal true, 1.even?
  assert_equal false, 2.even?
end
```

It seems the `def even?` doesn't do anything; if I change the method, it doesn't seem to work:

```
class ::Integer
  def even?
    (self % 2) != 0
  end
end
```

The test still succeeds.

I think this is because `even` is already defined in Ruby. Is that correct?  Why is this so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby core isn’t special, and the problem is that `even?` here doesn’t come from `Integer`, it comes from [`Fixnum`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-even-3F). And since `Fixnum` is lower in `1`’s ancestry than Integer, redefining it in `Integer` doesn’t have any effect, since never even gets called.

Redefining in `Fixnum` instead works fine:

```
1.even?  #=> false
class Fixnum; def even?; true; end end
1.even?  #=> true
```

And, for reference, here’s `1`’s ancestry:

```
1.class.ancestors  #=> [Fixnum, Integer, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

You can tell `even?` comes from `Fixnum` by getting a [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Method.html) object and then its [`owner`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Method.html#method-i-owner):

```
1.method(:even?).owner  #=> Fixnum
1.method(:ceil).owner   #=> Integer
```